# ETW event tracing in WPF 4+

Tags: wpf, etw

I am trying to use a Microsoft demo project which shows [how to do ETW event tracing in WPF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2008/09/26/etw-event-tracing-in-wpf/) as a basis for some specific profiling I want to do in an app I'm developing.

Compiled as is, the demo works fine. However, change the target framework from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4, and it breaks. Clearly there is some significant change between the framework versions.

The question is what changed, and (more importantly) is it possible to fix the demo?

#### My investigation so far

Adding a `Debug.WriteLine` to `FpsEventConsumer.EtwEventCallback` I see that in framework 4 either no events arrive or two events arrive, both with `Header.Guid` of `68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3`; one with `Header.Class.Type` of `UCE_GLASS_START` and the other with `UCE_GLYPHRUN_START`. Note that I also observe these events, among many others, when testing under framework 3.5.

By digging around in referencesource.microsoft.com I discovered that [`MS.Utility.EventTrace`'s static field `EventProvider`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Utility/Trace.cs,f9a5f9a841196abd,references) of type `MS.Utility.TraceProvider` controls what gets sent to ETW. Using reflection to access the event provider (since it's non-public) I observe that in 3.5 it starts with everything enabled (`_enabled` is `true`, `_flags` is `2147483647`, `_level` is `5`); and in 4 it starts with everything disabled (`_enabled` is false, `_keywords` is `0`, and `_level` is `0`). But changing those values with reflection doesn't seem to help the situation much. At best, on a very rare occasion I get a few events emitted before the `UCE_` ones mentioned above.

By placing a `WriteLine` in `TraceConsumer.ProcessTrace` as follows, I observe that the p/invoked call continues to block, so the problem isn't that the trace is being interrupted.

```
             ErrorCode errorCode = UnsafeEventTrace.ProcessTrace(handleArray, handleArray.Length,
                                                                 (FILETIME)startTime, (FILETIME)endTime);
+            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ProcessTrace: " + errorCode);
             if (errorCode != ERROR.SUCCESS)
             {
                 errorCode.OutputErrorMessage("TraceConsumer.ProcessTrace");
             }
```

Comment: I'm afraid it all changed much since the demo was created. Now you should use this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/. Also, if I remember well, currently you need to switch on WPF ETW events, before you'll be able to collect them.

Comment: @MaciekŚ., thanks. I will look into that, although my initial experimentation isn't very promising.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the answer was there all along in one of the referencesource files I looked at:

```
    /// ...
    /// TreatAsSafe:  it generates the GUID that is passed into the TraceProvider
    /// WPF versions prior to 4.0 used provider guid: {a42c77db-874f-422e-9b44-6d89fe2bd3e5}
    ///</SecurityNote>
    [SecurityCritical, SecurityTreatAsSafe]
    static EventTrace()
    {
        Guid providerGuid = new Guid("E13B77A8-14B6-11DE-8069-001B212B5009");
        ...
```

The following simple patch to `Sample.RunTrace` causes events to start flowing (although they no longer include the particular event which the demo uses for the FPS).

```
-            m_traceSession = TraceController.WpfController;
+            m_traceSession = typeof(System.Windows.Rect).Assembly.GetName().Version.Major == 3
+                ? TraceController.WpfController
+                : TraceController.GetController(new Guid("E13B77A8-14B6-11DE-8069-001B212B5009"), "WPF");
```